# Using System.Collections.Immutable with F# and Mono

Tags: f#, mono, xamarin, .net-4.5, immutability

I am trying to make use of the ImmutableDictionary in F# using Mono. I'm using the Xamarin IDE.

I have set my target framework to Mono/.Net4.5 and imported the System.Collections.Immutable using the built in Nuget package manager.

The following line

`open System.Collections.Immutable`

is generating the following two errors

`'/Users/UserName/Projects/Xamarin/OrderInfer/OrderInference/MyTest.fs(34,34): Error FS1109: A reference to the type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1' in assembly 'System.Runtime' was found, but the type could not be found in that assembly (FS1109) (MyTest)'`

`/Users/UserName/Projects/Xamarin/OrderInfer/OrderInference: Error FS1108: The type 'Lazy'2' is required here and is unavailable. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.ComponentModel.Composition, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. (FS1108) (OrderInference)`

The 2nd error suggests I need to reference System.ComponentModel.Composition. Am I able to use it in Mono? If so, is there another assembly I need to reference?

EDIT:
*Solution removed and reposted below as an answer*

Comment: According to http://go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.0&profile=4.0&assembly=System.ComponentModel.Composition the second should at least be partially OK.

Comment: I was able to get rid of these two errors by manually adding the System.ComponentModel assembly via the "Edit Reference" dialog box. The `open System.Collections.Immutable` no longer generates errors. However, I am still getting a `Type is not defined` error from the `new ImmutableDictionary<string string> line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImmutableDictionary is abstract so `new` won't work.  It does however provide a number of [create methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.immutable.immutabledictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
ImmutableDictionary.Create<string, string>()
```

Comment: He's using it in a type annotation. I don't see `new` anywhere. So it _should_ work.

Comment: Thanks. Although I didn't have a `new` method adding in a `wordPairs = ImmutableDictionary.Create<string, string>()` line below was enough to solve the problem.

Comment: Nitpick: `ImmutableDictionary<TKey, TValue>` isn't abstract (it's actually sealed). It's just that we don't provide any public constructors.

Comment: Who is this Immo guy to come in and nitpick? Who does he think he is? The creator of this assemble?... oh wait...

Comment: @ImmoLandwerth oh, I just saw [<AbstractClass>] on the web docs and assumed.  The classic programmer mistake.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be solved by adding a reference to: 'System.ComponentModel.Composition'. In Xamarin's IDE, this is done by using the Edit References Dialog which can be found by right-clicking on the reference in your project. Go to the All tab and search for `System.ComponentModel` and just add the `System.ComponentModel.Composition` assembly.

I now have the following two assemblies installed:

```
System.Collections.Immutable.dll
System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll
```

My code now reads:

```
open System
open System.ComponentModel.Composition
open System.Collections.Immutable

type wordPairs = { pairs:ImmutableDictionary<string, string>; count:int} 
let myPairs = {pairs = ImmutableDictionary.Create<string, string>(); count = 0}
```

Note: As gradbot pointed out (*and Immo Landwerth later nitpicked about* ;>> ), `ImmutableDictionary` is a <del>abstract</del> sealed class. <del>And as such, it has no public constructors.</del> So you need to use the `.Create` method.

Comment: Another nitpick: being sealed doesn't imply no public constructors :-)